# Testing SseEmitter ends with timeToWait error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test my SSE endpoint which uses `SseEmitter`:

```java
@GetMapping("/subscribe")
public SseEmitter subscribe() {
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(4000L);

    Disposable disposable = Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
            .map(e -> event().data("data" + e))
            .log()
            .subscribe(unchecked(sseEmitter::send));

    sseEmitter.onError(e -> log.error("SSE ERROR", e));

    sseEmitter.onTimeout(unchecked(() -> {
        log.info("SSE Timeout");
        sseEmitter.complete();
    }));

    sseEmitter.onCompletion(() -> {
        log.info("SSE COMPLETED");
        disposable.dispose();
    });

    return sseEmitter;
}
```

The test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(
        controllers = SseEmitterController.class
)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "36000")
class SimpleSseTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void test() {

        FluxExchangeResult<String> result = webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/subscribe")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType("text/event-stream")
                .returnResult(String.class);

        StepVerifier.create(result.getResponseBody())
                .expectNextCount(2)
                .thenCancel()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

But the test fails with this error:

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Async result for handler [SseEmitterController#subscribe()] was not set during the specified timeToWait=4000; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async result for handler [SseEmitterController#subscribe()] was not set during the specified timeToWait=4000

Does anyone know how do I to get rid of this error?

***I'm using spring-boot 2.6.8***

Comment: Why not just return the Flux? Doesn't seem like you need `SseEmitter` at all. But that could just be the result of simplification/anonymization of the code.

Comment: I get the same error with Flux @kaqqao

Comment: I quickly tested this in a real web environment both with `SseEmitter` and `Flux` and it worked fine, so I suspect it's something with the test setup that's not acting right.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me too in a real wen environment :)

Comment: When I set emitter.complete();
        return emitter; in the controller then is working, but this is not the desired behaviour. Did you somehow manage to work in the test ?